# How to localize a generic error messages partial in Rails 3.2.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using the following partial to display error messages for most of my models in Rails 3.2.3:

```
# _error_messages.html.erb

<% if object.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
    <h3><%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>
    prohibited this <%= object.class.to_s.underscore.humanize.downcase %> from being saved:</h3>        
    <p>There were problems with the following fields:</p>
    <ul>
        <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
<% end %>
```

This worked great until I decided to localize my application using `I18n`.

I created a new file `de.yml` for the German language content which contains this (among many other things):

```
# de.yml

errors: &errors
  format: ! '%{attribute} %{message}'
  messages:
    blank: muss ausgefüllt werden
  template:
    body: ! 'Bitte überprüfen Sie die folgenden Felder:'
    header:
      one: ! 'Konnte %{model} nicht speichern: ein Fehler.'
      other: ! 'Konnte %{model} nicht speichern: %{count} Fehler.'

etc. etc. etc.
```

Now how can I use this content in my error messages?

Especially the line `<%= object.class.to_s.underscore.humanize.downcase %>` puzzles me. I tried something like `<%= t 'activerecord.errors.template.header', :model => object.model_name.human %>` but without any luck.

Can anybody help?

I read the Rails guide on localization three times already, but I am stuck here.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the answer myself this time, thanks to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093935/rails-i18n-with-translated-model-names).

I simply changed my `_error_messages.html.rb` partial to:

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
    <h3><%= t('errors.template.header', :model => object.class.model_name.human, :count => object.errors.count) %></h3>
    <p><%= t('errors.template.body') %></p>
    <ul>
        <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Now it works and I am happy :-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should set your locale by this:

## application.rb

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :de
```

Second, your locale file should look like this:

## de.yml

```
de:
  activerecord:
    models:
      order: Заказ
    attributes:
      order:
        link: Ссылка на модель часов
        name: Имя
        phone: Телефон
        accept_message: Комментарий к заказу
        decline_message: Причина отказа
        finish_message: Комментарий к заказу
    errors:
      models:
        order:
          attributes:
            link:
              blank: не может быть пустой
            phone:
              invalid: должен содержать только цифры. Пример: 9208003020 или 2716070.
              blank: не может быть пустым
            name:
              blank: не может быть пустым
            decline_message:
              blank: не может быть пустой
```

Comment: OK, thanks. My file looks the same as yours. What I posted above is just an *exerpt* of my `yml` file.

Comment: Let's try debug. Replace `<% object.errors.full_messages.each` on `<% raise(object.errors.full_messages.inspect)` What's output it returns?

Comment: Thanks, I think my initial question may have been a little misleading. I found the solution myself this time and posted it above. Thanks for your help though!!