# How to internationalize (I18n) generic error messages on a failed validation in Rails 3.1?

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nested-forms

I would like to be able to provide internationalized, helpful error messages.

I have a generic error message partial view rendering for a nested form submission

```
    # _error_messages.html.erb - Fragment
    ...

    <strong><%= t('errors.template.body') %> </strong>       
    <ul>
      <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %> </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>

    ...
```

I get the internationalized body message, however, I cannot figure out how to replace the attribute or, more specifically, the ":blank" error for that model field (i.e., validates_presence_of :name) validation despite numerous yaml iterations.

Here is a fragment from my yaml

```
en:
  errors: &errors
    format: ! '%{attribute} -- %{message}'
      messages:
        accepted: must be accepted
        blank: must not be blank
        body: ! 'There were problems with the following fields:'


    activemodel:
        attributes:
          family_wizard: 
            children: kids
```

And I wrote the yaml like that because when I inspect the error object passed to the partial when I leave the child's name field blank (:validates_presence_of :name) looks like this:

```
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007111111C111111 @base=#<FamilyWizard id: nil, ...>, 
    @messages {:children=>["must not be blank"]}>
```

But the only error message I can get out is:

**There were problems with the following fields:**

- Children -- must not be blank

An ideal solution error message would look like this:

**There were problems with the following fields:**

- **Kids** -- **the name** must not be blank

This Stack Overflow question ([How to localize a generic error messages partial in Rails 3.2.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536518/how-to-localize-a-generic-error-messages-partial-in-rails-3-2-3)) was on the right track, but it's missing the activemodel/activerecord validation part I would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is I have the wrong scope because of two issues with my yaml file. The wrong spacing and the wrong lable. It should be activerecord instead of activemodel and the activerecord scope should be at the same level as the error scope in the tree.

To have the model's attributes translated (i.e., Children to Kids) the yaml looks like this:

```
en:
  errors: &errors
    format: ! '%{attribute} -- %{message}'
      messages:
        accepted: must be accepted
        blank: must not be blank
        body: ! 'There were problems with the following fields:'


  activerecord:
    attributes:
      family_wizard: 
        children: kids
```

The two resources that helped me get the answer were these:

- [How can I translate form fields name in error messages?](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/803246)
- [Minimal I18n with Rails 3.2](http://rubylearning.com/blog/2012/07/24/minimal-i18n-with-rails-3-2/)

Comment: what mean "errors: &errors", the "&errors" as helpful for something? Can explain that plz?